# windows.setTimeout() making my infopath form very slow

Tags: infopath, javascript, jquery

this is my code for InfoPath postback

```
window.onload = function() { 
window.setTimeout(getData, 1000); 
} 


function getData(){ 
getEmployee(); 
getCompany(); 
window.setTimeout(getData, 1000); //To handle IP's form postback 
} 

function getEmployee(){ 
var employee = []; 
$().SPServices({ 
operation: "GetListItems", 
listName: "employee", 
CAMLViewFields: "", 
CAMLQuery:"<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Inactive0'/><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq></Where></Query>", 
async: false, 
completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
employee.push({label:$(this).attr("ows_Title"),value:$(this).attr("ows_ID")}); 
}); 
} 
}); 

$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T26']").autocomplete({ 
source: employee, 
minLength: 2, 
select: function( event, ui) { 
alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label + "' with an ID of " + ui.item.value) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value); 
$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T27']").focus(); 
$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T26']").val(ui.item.label); 
$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T27']").val(ui.item.value); 
event.preventDefault(); 
return false; 
}, 
focus: function(event, ui){ 
event.preventDefault(); 
$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T26']").val(ui.item.label); 
      return false;
    }
}); 


function getCompany(){ 
var company = []; 
$().SPServices({ 
operation: "GetListItems", 
listName: "company", 
CAMLViewFields: "", 
CAMLQuery:"<Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Inactive'/><Value Type='Boolean'>0</Value></Eq></Where></Query>", 
async: false, 
completefunc: function (xData, Status) { 
$(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() { 
company.push({label:$(this).attr("ows_Title"),value:$(this).attr("ows_ID")}); 
}); 
} 
}); 

$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T28']").autocomplete({ 
source: company, 
minLength: 2, 

select: function( event, ui) { 
alert(ui.item ? ("You picked '" + ui.item.label + "' with an ID of " + ui.item.value) : "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value); 
$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T29']").focus(); 
$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T28']").val(ui.item.label); 
$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T29']").val(ui.item.value); 
event.preventDefault();
            return false;
    },
focus: function(event, ui){ 
$("input[id$='FormControl0_V1_I1_T28']").val(ui.item.label); 
event.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
}); 
}
```

In the functions getEmployee() and getCompany() i am using autocomplete for the textbxox. The windows.setTimeout(getData, 1000) function makes my form gets very slow - it is getting the postback every 1 second. 
Is there any other solution I could use that would make my form autocompletion faster?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you understand the point of the JavaScript function there.
The command

> window.setTimeout(getData, 1000);

will wait for 1000 milliseconds (1 second) and then execute the method.  That is exactly what it was built for.

I don't understand why you need that timeout. The Ajax will execute and you can bind to that complete function.